# What happens if two different asynchronous callbacks start two different synchronous methods?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit, synchronous

Suppose I have two different apis(let api1 & api2). When the response of api1 arrives, I call a synchronous method `foo1()`. Similarly, when  the response of api2 arrives, I call another synchronous method `foo2()`. Here is the situation- I call both the apis at the same time. Response for api1 arrives and method `foo1()` is called. Meanwhile, the response from api2 also arrives and the method `foo2()` is invoked.

My question is that what will be the order of execution? Will `foo2()` wait for `foo1()` to complete or it will be executed parallaly?

Comment: my question is, why havent you tried it to find out yourself?

Comment: what do you mean with "synchronous method"? Marked as `synchronized` or the one which is not asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i tried it myself, thanks to @DroiDev. I used [Anko library](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) for the asynchronous tasks.Here is the code:

```
  doAsync {
        Log.d("ASYNC", "Async A started")
        foo1()
        uiThread {
            Log.d("ASYNC", "Async A done")
        }
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000)

    doAsync {
        Log.d("ASYNC", "Async B started")
        foo2()
        uiThread {
            Log.d("ASYNC", "Async B done")
        }
    }
}

fun foo1() {
    Log.d("ASYNC", "foo1() called")
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    Log.d("ASYNC", "foo1() done")
}

fun foo2() {
    Log.d("ASYNC", "foo2() called")
    Log.d("ASYNC", "foo2() done")
}
```

Here is the Result/Log which i got:

```
07-12 11:44:55.195 23990-24054/gemini.com.jetpack D/ASYNC: Async A started
foo1() called
07-12 11:44:56.195 23990-24028/gemini.com.jetpack D/ASYNC: Async B started
foo2() called
07-12 11:44:56.205 23990-24028/gemini.com.jetpack D/ASYNC: foo2() done
07-12 11:44:56.215 23990-23990/gemini.com.jetpack D/ASYNC: Async B done
07-12 11:44:58.195 23990-24054/gemini.com.jetpack D/ASYNC: foo1() done
07-12 11:44:58.205 23990-23990/gemini.com.jetpack D/ASYNC: Async A done
```

Hence, the method foo2() will not wait for foo1() to be completed.